# Upgrade SharePoint 2010 For Internet Sites Enterprise to Full Enterprise version without reinstallation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a server with Full SharePoint 2010 Enterprise installed, but the SharePoint 2010 For Internet Sites Enterprise license was used on installed.

The full functionality is required on the site.

Is it possible to upgrade the functionality of the installation without doing a full reinstall or recreation of the farm.

Comment: A reinstall shouldn't be necessary, however I never tried from FIS to Enterprise. Check the Update and Migration > Convert farm license type?

Answer (score 1):

Internet Sites is only a license.  The bits are identical and you do not need to do anything but logically assign the license to your SharePoint Server(s).  No configuration changes required.

Comment: central admin says server is in enterprise mode, but features are not available

Comment: Have you gone to Upgrade and Migration -> Enable Enterprise Features?

Comment: On Enable Enterprise Features Enterprise is selected and the controls grayed out.  On Enable features on sites the features set is standard.  On Convert License Type the Product Key box is disabled.